# What I do wrong? Django objects filter

Tags: python, django

I try show post only from 30 days. What I do worng?

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    days = 30
    posts = Post.objects.filter(Post.publish < timezone.now() - timedelta(days=days))
    #posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard', 'posts': posts})
```

error

```
TypeError at /account/
unorderable types: DeferredAttribute() < datetime.datetime()
```

Comment: You could have solved the problem by yourself reading the documentation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intead of `<` sign inside filter method you should use `__lt` lookup attached to field name:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(publish__lt=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=days))
```

Comment: FieldError at /account/
Cannot resolve keyword 'publish_lt' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, body, id, location, publish, title

Comment: @JestemPokrowcem Double underscore, not single. That's how you access these methods.